# Datalayer Analytics

Tags: analytics

i have the next datalayer of purchase to send google analytics:

```
dataLayer.push({
                      'event': 'ActivarTransaccion',
                      'ecommerce': {
                        'purchase': {
                          'actionField': {
                            'id': '46234462',  
                            'affiliation': '001000', 
                            'revenue': 189,
                            'tax': 0.00
                          },
                          'products': [{               
                            'id': 'PGA720084778', 
                            'name': 'PGA720084778', 
                            'category': 'category',
                            'price': 189, 
                            'brand': 'brand', 
                            'quantity': 1, 
                            'dimension1': '',
                            'dimension2': 'K 1200',
                            'dimension3': 'GT',
                            'dimension4': '',
                            'dimension5': 'A',
                            'dimension6': 'dim',
                            'dimension7': 'dim',
                            'dimension8': 'date',
                            'dimension9': 'moto',
                            'dimension10': 'cp',
                            'metric2': '42',
                            'metric3': '22',
                            'metric4': '10',
                            'metric5': '10',    
                            'metric6': '189'
                           }]
                        }
                      }
                    });
```

However, the data is not sending to google analytics to register ecommerce, what is wrong, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like it fires correctly. The data layer itself doesn't send to Google Analytics, so have you checked how your Google Tag Manager configuration is set up? The way this is structured here would mean that an event tag would send the data.

Creating a tag like below would tell the tag to fire on the 'ActivarTransaccion' data layer event and to use the data layer for the ecommerce information.

**Tag type :** Universal Analytics

**Track type :** Event (then add cat, action, label)

**Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features:** true

**Use Data Layer:** true

**Trigger:** event equals ActivarTransaccion (custom event trigger)

Once that is complete and tested in the GTM debug mode, you will also have to enable Enhanced Ecommerce in the view by going to Admin > View Column > Enhanced Ecommerce Settings > Enable Ecommerce and Enable Enhanced Ecommerce.

If these are already done, the next step would be to check the logic on the site that dynamically pushes this code.